# Trying to deploy a Meteor app -- mup setup error

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here? I'm on a Windows machine. This happens with an app that I've built myself. I also get the same error on Meteor's hello world app. Thanks in advance.

mup init works fine, but when I try to run mup setup, I receive this error message.

- Installing Node.js
  events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
  Error: All configured authentication methods failed
  at tryNextAuth (C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\node_modules\nodemiral\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:290:17)
  at SSH2Stream.onUSERAUTH_FAILURE (C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\node_modules\nodemiral\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:469:5)
  at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
  at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:172:7)
  at parsePacket (C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\node_modules\nodemiral\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:3652:10)
  at SSH2Stream._transform (C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\node_modules\nodemiral\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:555:13)
  at SSH2Stream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
  at SSH2Stream._read (C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\node_modules\nodemiral\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:213:15)
  at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)

//--------------- Below is the info from my mup.json file ----------

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "username": "xxxxxx",
      "password": "xxxxxx"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": false,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.40",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server.
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "alp-new",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": ".",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@candidate.55.mongolayer.com:10503,candidate.16.mongolayer.com:11209/alp-telescope?replicaSet=set-5634fd304bed0503ed000ade"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 30
}
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you deploying to? Make sure to use Ubuntu 14.04 or higher.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to deploy to a Ubuntu 14.04 x64 droplet. I'ts the 'setup' step that is throwing the error -- not to the 'deploy' stage yet.

Comment: can you paste your mup.json file?

Comment: Thanks @Ruby_Pry -- I've added the mup.json file info above

Comment: Does the user that you are using in you mup have permissions to run commands in super user mode (or sudo)?

Comment: You are receiving an ssh authorization error. I recommend using SSH to authenticate. What hosting service are you deploying to?

Comment: Deploying to Digital Ocean. I will look into SSH authentication. I think you might be right about this.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssh-based-authentication-with-sudo, you need to ensure that your key file is not protected by a passphrase. Not sure if you are deploying to Digital Ocean, but this article can still serve as a good reference regardless:

http://meteortips.com/deployment-tutorial/digitalocean-part-1/

Comment: Thank you for the link - bookmarked. I followed the instructions to setup and SSH key on my computer and created a droplet on Digital Ocean with the info. Tried mup setup again, but I'm still getting the exact same error message. I've got nodeVersion "5.0.0" on my computer -- tried using that in the mup.json file. I also tried nodeVersion "0.10.40" -- same error.

Comment: Still working on the instructions at https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssh-based-authentication-with-sudo to ensure my key file is not protected by passphrase. But I'm on Windows machine and am having trouble translating the sudo commands. However, my username is "root" so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: You should use 0.10.40. You have to set up the id_rsa.ssh in your root directory per the article, same as you would for github or any other ssh based authentication.